# MethodInfo.Invoke is failing when parameter is of type Enum

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, json.net, jsonconvert

I'm having one method like the following, where `Days` is an `Enum` having values from `Sunday` to `Saturday`, Which I'm calling using reflection. I'm having lots of similar methods with different signatures And the input parameters are also dynamic which I'm getting as a JSON.

```
Public Sub ReflectionMethod(ByVal stringParam As String, ByVal enumParam As Days)
    Console.WriteLine($"Executed:ReflectionMethod | stringParam : {stringParam}; enumParam : {enumParam}")
End Sub
```

The following code is used to parse the JSON and call the method using reflection.

```
Dim inputJson As String = "['Sample Input',2]"
Dim lstObjects As List(Of Object) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Object))(inputJson)
Dim method As MethodInfo = consoleObject.GetType.GetMethod("ReflectionMethod")
method.Invoke(consoleObject, lstObjects.ToArray)
```

Throwing the following error while executing the above code, During debugging noticed that `method.Invoke()` method is getting failed nothing wrong with the deserialization.

> Exception: Object of type 'System.Int64' cannot be converted to type 'VBConsole.Days'.

**Please note:** This is not the actual code that I'm using, just created a console application for easy debugging, and an answer in `C#` is also appreciated, That's why tagged it to `c#`

Comment: Well to me,  seems pretty clear what the exception is.  Your method is returning an int64, and your expected a Days value.  Is your real question how to convert the results to the enum?

Comment: `method.Invoke(consoleObject, new { lstObjects[0], Enum.ToObject(typeof(Days), lstObjects[1]) })`

Comment: For the record, there already exists a `DayOfWeek` enumeration, so you probably ought to have used that. If you were going to create your own then it should have been named `Day`, unless you have applied the `Flags` attribute and used powers of 2 for the values. `Enum` names should be singular by default and only pluralised if you specifically want to be able to use composite values. Of course, I don't know for sure that that is not the case here so, if it is, ignore what I said.

Answer (score 2):

In order to pass your array of JSON values into a method to be invoked by reflection, you must deserialize each JSON value to the required argument type.  This can be done as follows:

```
Public Sub InvokeMethodWithJsonArguments(ByVal consoleObject As Object, ByVal methodName As String, ByVal inputJson As String)
    Dim lstObjects As List(Of JToken) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of JToken))(inputJson)    ' Deserialize to an intermediate list of JToken values
    Dim method As MethodInfo = consoleObject.GetType.GetMethod(methodName)
    Dim parameterTypes = method.GetParameters().Select(Function(p) p.ParameterType)                     ' Get the required type of each argument.
    Dim args = lstObjects.Zip(parameterTypes, Function(first, second) first.ToObject(second)).ToArray() ' Deserialize each JToken to the corresponding required type
    method.Invoke(consoleObject, args)                                                                  ' Invoke with the deserialized arguments.
End Sub
```

Notes:

- I am assuming you need a solution that does not hardcode the argument types.
- [`MethodInfo.GetParameters()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters) returns an array of parameter information matching the signature of the method to be invoked.
- [`JToken.ToObject(Type)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject.htm) deserializes a JSON token to a type specified in runtime.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vmwBvx).